# Cosmos DB missing Jupyter Notebook option

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Cosmos DB.

Question - I couldn't find "New Notebook" option in my existing Cosmos DB and even checked by creating the new Cosmos DB account also. And I have Cosmos DB running in Jupyter Notebook supported regions.

It seems like I'm missing some thing. Any comment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is related to ChaosDB vulnerability. Not something that can be covered here on Stack Overflow, as it's a service-specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked my account which does have notebooks enabled.

Hovering over the New Notebook option and I see this:

[image]

I suspect this is related to the security vulnerability fixed recently: https://www.theregister.com/2021/08/27/chaos_db_azure_cosmos_flaw/

Comment: I don't see that "New Notebook" option also.. And yes. it's related the security vulnerability. I'm trying to find out if we have Jupyter Notebook enabled in our Cosmos DB or not. But, I don't even see the option to create/enable notebooks.. Is there any way I can check if Jupyter Notebook feature is enabled in my Cosmos DB?

Comment: @S It seems likely that the option to enable on an account would be disabled as well (you'll need to check the docs for how to enable).

Comment: I tried to refer the docs but non of the docs addressing the issue i'm facing.. It's bit strange.. As mentioned, I tried to create all together a new Cosmos DB account and containers but still don't see.. Looks like it's time for me to raise ticket with Microsoft..

Comment: @siva Theory: CosmosDB notebook creation is disabled while security issue is resolved.

Comment: I came to know that Microsoft has already fixed the issue and suggested customers to regenerate the keys for their databases to be on safe side. If vulnerability already fixed I believe I should be able to see the notebook option correct? Anyways I reached out to MS on this hope i will get answer soon.

Comment: @siva - as I mentioned in my comment under your question - not something that can be covered here on Stack Overflow - it's a transient issue related to a discovered vulnerability.